# Find parcels dupliactes in different street names

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arctoolbox, arccatalog

I want to find duplicates in parcels, deep in streets basis.

My schema goes like this; Neighborhood >> Block >> Parcel >> Street

Let's say I have Street1, Street2 and Street3, all of them might have duplicated parcels. I want to do it through a model, to search all the streets "individually" then give me results of duplicates if there any.

Comment: Hey - This question is a bit confusing as it doesn't really explain what you are trying to achieve. are you looking for duplicate parcel polygon boundaries (entire polygon) or duplicate parcel line work (one coincidental boundary line)?